# R - Error in contour.default(x, y, z) : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

Tags: r, contour

I am a newbie in this field, trying to practice creat 3Dplot - contour.
I write this simple script

```
z <- outer(x,y, function (x,y)cos (y)/(1+x ^2))
contour (x,y,z)
contour (x,y,z, nlevels =45 , add = T)
za <-( z- t(z))/2
contour (x,y, za, nlevels =15)
```

and get the error:

> *Error in contour.default(x, y, z) : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected*.

I know that someone has coped with a similar error, but most answers involved creating a proper matrix z. In my case, I think I have done it well with the "outer".

So how I can fix it?

Comment: You need to specify `x` and `y` values for each point first. E.g. `x <- y <- seq(0,4,length.out=100)`

Comment: I had called x, y as:  x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), but it did n't work, until I tried your suggestion. It works now. Thanks a lot!